# Why does the mocked method run but .toBeenCalled asserts 0

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

This is the test for a very simple counter component with an external store. The store is successfully mocked as shown by the log statements but Jest doesn't count the execution of methods.

The test code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import { mocked } from 'ts-jest/utils';

import { App } from './App';
import { store } from './store';

jest.mock('./store', () => ({
  store: {
    create() {
      return {
        counter: 50,
        increment: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => console.log('Running mock increment')),
        decrement: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => console.log('Running mock decrement')),
      };
    },
  },
}));

beforeAll(() => (mockedStore = mocked(store, true).create()));

let mockedStore = mocked(store, true).create();

test('The increment Button to call store.increment', () => {
  const { getByText } = render(<App />);
  const button = getByText('+');
  userEvent.click(button);
  expect(mockedStore.increment).toBeCalled();
});

test('The decrement Button to call store.decrement', () => {
  const { getByText } = render(<App />);
  const button = getByText('-');
  userEvent.click(button);
  expect(mockedStore.decrement).toBeCalled();
});

test('The counter value is displayed in the component', () => {
  const { getByTestId } = render(<App />);
  const output = getByTestId('output');
  expect(output).toHaveTextContent(mockedStore.counter.toString());
});
```

And the logged result:

```
 FAIL  src/App.test.tsx
  ● Console

    console.log src/App.tsx:16
      increment from the component
    console.log src/App.test.tsx:14
      Running mock increment
    console.log src/App.tsx:26
      decrement from the component
    console.log src/App.test.tsx:15
      Running mock decrement

  ● The increment Button to call store.increment

    expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalled()

    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0

      27 |   const button = getByText('+');
      28 |   userEvent.click(button);
    > 29 |   expect(mockedStore.increment).toBeCalled();
         |                                 ^
      30 | });
      31 |
      32 | test('The decrement Button to call store.decrement', () => {

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.test.tsx:29:33)

  ● The decrement Button to call store.decrement

    expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalled()

    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0

      34 |   const button = getByText('-');
      35 |   userEvent.click(button);
    > 36 |   expect(mockedStore.decrement).toBeCalled();
         |                                 ^
      37 | });
      38 |
      39 | test('The counter value is displayed in the component', () => {

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.test.tsx:36:33)
```

The whole project is accessible here: https://github.com/pixelkritzel/jest-2020-07-27

Comment: How is `mockedStore` related to the rendering of the component? It's the mock implementation returned from `jest.mock("./store", ...)` that will be used in `App`.

Comment: It just imports store and assigns its own property

https://github.com/pixelkritzel/jest-2020-07-27/blob/master/src/App.tsx

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. My question is: how do you think the mock store you create using `mockedStore = mocked(store, true).create()` (in more than once place, actually) is related to the store the component is accessing? How do you think it gets into the component? And, if it does, why do you think you also need to `jest.mock` the import? You have *two separate* mocks of the same thing - one's being used by the component (the one that has the logs in), the other by the tests. That's why you see no calls.

Comment: In the meantime I found out if move the methods outside of the mock and reference them it works.

https://github.com/pixelkritzel/jest-2020-07-27/blob/works/src/App.test.tsx

Also as the log indicates the mock methods run but aren't tracked by Jest. I just want to understand why Jest isn't able to track the call if I define the mock methods inside the module mock.

Answer (score 2):

So I finally figured it out. The working solution with explaining comments.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';

import { App } from './App';
import { store } from './store';

// We have to define the methods outside of the retuned object because jest.fn
// uses this internally and it gets messed by defining it inside an object
// Outside of the mock implementation we have to prefix the method name with
// mock else the babel transpiler will ignore the methods
const mockIncrement = jest.fn();
const mockDecrement = jest.fn();

// This intercepts the import of store
jest.mock('./store', () => ({
  store: {
    // Because it's a named export we need to prive a top level object with the exported name
    create() {
      return {
        counter: 50,
        increment: mockIncrement, // referencing the above mocked function
        decrement: mockDecrement, // referencing the above mocked function
      };
    },
  },
}));

let mockedStore = store.create();

// because the mocked methods exist outside of the mocked module we can't simply
// reinitialize the module but have to call mockClear on the methods
afterEach(() => {
  mockIncrement.mockClear();
  mockDecrement.mockClear();
});

test('The increment Button to call store.increment', () => {
  const { getByText } = render(<App />);
  const button = getByText('+');
  userEvent.click(button);
  expect(mockedStore.increment).toBeCalled();
});

test('The decrement Button to call store.decrement', () => {
  const { getByText } = render(<App />);
  const button = getByText('-');
  userEvent.click(button);
  expect(mockedStore.decrement).toBeCalled();
});

test('The counter value is displayed in the component', () => {
  const { getByTestId } = render(<App />);
  const output = getByTestId('output');
  expect(output).toHaveTextContent(mockedStore.counter.toString());
});
```